# How to disable all checks on the angular component template?

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to add an existing angular to Nx. I'd like to suppress all the template checks so that I can run it. I will turn all the checks back later. It's so distracting to trying to fix so many files.

```
"compilerOptions": {
 "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
 "strict": false,
 "noImplicitReturns": true,
 "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
 "strictNullChecks": false
},
"angularCompilerOptions": {
 "strictInjectionParameters": true,
 "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
 "strictTemplates": false,
 "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false
}
```

I tried all the above, particularly `strictNullChecks`, `strictTemplates`, and `fullTemplateTypeCheck`, it still not working. I keep getting this types of errors:

```
[src]="chat.contact.avatar"
Object is possibly 'undefined'
```

All I want is to just disable all template checks. This application is working fine. Nx has way more constraints that I will deal with later.

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

It seems like the only tsconfig that matters is the one in the **apps** folder. I didn't touch the the tsconfig in the apps folder because that's not where the problematic codes were. After I changed, all the errors went away. I even, turned back the tsconfig in the libs folders the way the were before, the errors still didn't show up.

Should I conclude that the only tsconfig that matters is the one in the apps folder?

Comment: I'm using Angular 13. Btw, I am trying to disable everything check on the template that's why I turned `strictTemplates ` off.

Comment: fullTemplateTypeCheck is deprecated in 13, strictTemplates anything with strict**** should be used with false

Comment: Do you have multiple .tsconfig project?

Comment: yes. I have this starter project that I am trying to organize in several libraries using NX. I move parts of the code in several projects. Therefore, I have more than one tsconfig now, i.e. per library

Comment: Here's the starter project https://themeforest.net/item/fuse-angularjs-material-design-admin-template/12931855?gclid=CjwKCAiAn5uOBhADEiwA_pZwcOmZIB7xzz4x05UmfYsg7oYCy-E33MZB8SagCiiUNRF9WRFFsLfNQBoCtKgQAvD_BwE

Comment: I am sure you did, but will still ask. Did you set the same  "strictTemplates": false,
 in all .tsconfig files?

Comment: @Vega see the update. It seems like the only tsconfig that matters is the one in the `apps` folder. I don't understand.